# Automatically replace cell value based on another cell - VBA

Tags: vba, excel, replace, cell

So, i´m new at this...

I have this code:

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change()


    If Range("C2").Value = "T0" Then
        Range("C4").Value = "1"
    End If


End Sub
```

But excel keeps on giving me a "Run-time error 28 : Out of stack space"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If target.address="$C$2" and target.value = "T0" Then
        Range("C4").Value = "1"
    End If
End Sub`

Checking the target address being C2 is optional, I was assuming that C2 is changed which is what you are trapping.

Comment: Yes, correct. Worked like a charm. Many thanks Nathan

Comment: No probs, give me some rep points and mark as correct if you could pls.